# How to display a scrolling roll of names?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-impress

I have to organize a roll call vote with over 100 people.

The next 4 or 5 names must be displayed on a screen, so that voters see their name and prepare to speak up. Ideally, this is a scrolling list that can go faster/slower, or that can be paused/resumed.

How can I do that? With Impress/Powerpoint? Calc/Excel? any another program?

One requirement is for the scrolling list to take little time to prepare. Here's why: while 200 names are registered, only about 100 people will show up. So the scrolling list can be prepared beforehand, but some names will be removed at the last minute.

Comment: I suppose you run the call in a tool from where you can quickly extract participants. Why not just copy the list to Excel and scroll manually?

Comment: Yes so far I'm using Excel, two window mode, with one spreadsheet for the voting roll, and another to show the names in fullscreen. However there is no scrolling, just an update of the names. I don't even know if it's possible to have a movie-like scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
Dim iFlag As Boolean

Dim i As Integer

Sub MoveDown()

If iFlag Then

iFlag = False

Else

If i = 12 Then 'how many pages you need

i = 0

Else

i = i + 1

End If

Range("A" & i * 28 + 17).Select

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:0:2"), "movedown"

End If

End Sub

Sub StopM()

iFlag = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Where your code is supposed to run? How it address "One requirement is for the scrolling list to take little time to prepare"? Also your code seems to jump to next page instead of scrolling.